# useEffect not refreshing or Triggering on Adding New Friends

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const {Account,flag,setfriends} = useContext(AccountContext);
  const [text,settext] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const get = async() => {
        // if(friends.length !== 0) return
        const res = await getFriends(Account._id);
        const data = res.data?.friends;
        const filterData = data.filter(ele=>ele.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
        setfriends(filterData);
    }
    get(); //want to refetch data when new friend added
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  },[flag,text]);
```

//User.jsx

```
const {setperson} = useContext(PersonContext);

    const {Account,flag,setflag} = useContext(AccountContext);
    const add = async() => {
        const data = {
            user:userinfo,
            info,
        }
        await addFriend(data);
        setflag(!flag); **changing context flag which will recall upper useEffect but not callingi it
    };
```

**plese help me to Recall the upper useEffect it is not calling again when context flag changes**

// AccountContext.jsx

```
import React,{createContext, useState,useRef,useEffect} from 'react'
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
export const AccountContext = createContext(null);

const AccountProvider = ({children}) => {
    const socket = useRef();
    const [Account,setAccount] = useState();
    const [activeUsers,setactiveUsers] = useState([]);
    const [flag,setflag] = useState(false);
    const [friends,setfriends] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.current = io('ws://localhost:8000')
    },[])
    return (
        <AccountContext.Provider value={{Account,setAccount,activeUsers,setactiveUsers,flag,setflag,socket,friends,setfriends}}>{children}</AccountContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AccountProvider
```

**These is Account Provider where i have saved freinds list**

---

Comment: could you please aslso share what did you provide in Account.Context.Provider value?

Comment: i have added the account.jsx

Comment: Probably a silly question but, you haven't forgot to wrap the Components where you need context values inside <AccountProvider> ... </AccountProvider> right?

Comment: Bro i have also wrapped it in App.js